# Cross-origin request blocked from React

Tags: php, reactjs, cors

I am making an application with ReactJS and PHP in the backend. Now React is listening to port 3000 and PHP to port 80.
So when a POST request is made, it shows it is a cross-origin request.

To handle this I tried "proxy" in react but that did not work.
After this, I thought to change the config of apache server and add port 3000 as well.
To do this I followed this link [here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/apache/configure-apache-web-site-to-use-multiple-ports/)
but it did not work.

This is the error I get
...
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

...

And when I remove the changes, it works fine.
Please help. I am stuck here for hours now.

**UPDATE**
The suggested solution in the as proposed duplicate works when I use fetch() but does not work when I use Axios. Can not figure out the reason for this.

Comment: You could add ```Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"``` to your apache conf

Comment: @Maikel anywhere specific in that file??

Answer (score 0):

Change in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
     AllowOverride all
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Add/activate module

```
 a2enmod headers
```

Restart service

```
/etc/init.t/apache2 restart
```

Comment: It did not work bro...Still the same CORS issue.

Comment: It does not work with Axios but works fine with fetch()